# SVG rendering in a Pygame application. Prior to Pygame 2.0, Pygame did not support SVG. Then how did you load it?

Tags: python, svg, pygame, widget, pygame-surface

In a [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) application, I would like to render resolution-free GUI widgets described in SVG.

How can I achieve this?

(I like the [OCEMP GUI](http://ocemp.sourceforge.net/gui.html) toolkit, but it seems to be bitmap-dependent for its rendering.)

Comment: Is there a different answer / library that applies to 2011? (becuase its been been 3 years). I've seen squirtle used to load maps created in **inkscape**.

Comment: Squirtle is still not supporting much of SVG afaik and getting it to run with PyGame probably also requires some work. I'm searching for a long time for support of SVG drawing under Windows and 64 Bit Python and I think I have to give up.

Comment: Time passes, new possibilities emerge. See my answer below, but wait, there's more! pynanosvg has binary package for Windows!

Comment: pynanosvg is no longer supported. We need an updated solution.

Comment: **SVG files are supported with Pygame Version 2.0**. Since Version 2.0.2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a complete example which combines hints by other people here.
It should render a file called test.svg from the current directory.  It was tested on Ubuntu 10.10, python-cairo 1.8.8, python-pygame 1.9.1, python-rsvg 2.30.0.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import array
import math

import cairo
import pygame
import rsvg

WIDTH = 512
HEIGHT = 512

data = array.array('c', chr(0) * WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4)
surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(
    data, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIDTH * 4)

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
svg = rsvg.Handle(file="test.svg")
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
svg.render_cairo(ctx)

screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
image = pygame.image.frombuffer(data.tostring(), (WIDTH, HEIGHT),"ARGB")
screen.blit(image, (0, 0)) 
pygame.display.flip() 

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    clock.tick(15)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit
```

Comment: any particular reason not to use `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))` directly instead of creating this `window` object that is never used?

Comment: `TypeError: cannot use a str to initialize an array with typecode 'c'`

Comment: You no longer need to initialise the data array explicitly.  Leave out the call to array.array and instead do surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height); buf = surface.get_data(); image = pygame.image.frombuffer(buf, (width, height), "ARGB").  This will work in python3 as well as python2.  Source: https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html And yes, I know it's a very old question, but it still ranks highly in search results for pygame+cairo, so worth keeping up to date.  The pygame wiki page is badly out of date at the moment.

Comment: Since Version 2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html).

Answer (score 17):

**SVG files are supported with Pygame Version 2.0**. Since Version 2.0.2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html):

```py
surface = pygame.image.load('my.svg')
```

Before Pygame 2, you had to implement [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) loading with other libraries. Below are some ideas on how to do this.

---

A very simple solution is to use [CairoSVG](https://cairosvg.org/). With the function `cairosvg.svg2png`, an [Vector Graphics (SVG)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) files can be directly converted to an [Portable Network Graphics (PNG)] file

Install [CairoSVG](https://pypi.org/project/CairoSVG/).

```
pip install CairoSVG
```

Write a function that converts a SVF file to a PNG ([`ByteIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)) and creates a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object may look as follows:

```py
import cairosvg
import io

def load_svg(filename):
    new_bites = cairosvg.svg2png(url = filename)
    byte_io = io.BytesIO(new_bites)
    return pygame.image.load(byte_io)
```

See also [Load SVG](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_surface_and_image.md#load-svg)

---

An alternative is to use *svglib*. However, there seems to be a problem with transparent backgrounds. There is an issue about this topic [How to make the png background transparent? #171](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/171).

Install [svglib](https://pypi.org/project/svglib/).

```
pip install svglib
```

A function that parses and rasterizes an SVG file and creates a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object may look as follows:

```py
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
import io

def load_svg(filename):
    drawing = svg2rlg(filename)
    str = drawing.asString("png")
    byte_io = io.BytesIO(str)
    return pygame.image.load(byte_io)
```

---

Anther simple solution is to use *pynanosvg*. The downside of this solution is that *nanosvg* is no longer actively supported and does not work with Python 3.9. [pynanosvg](https://github.com/ethanhs/pynanosvg) can be used to load and rasterize [Vector Graphics (SVG)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) files. Install [Cython](https://cython.org/) and [pynanosvg](https://github.com/ethanhs/pynanosvg):

```
pip install Cython
pip install pynanosvg
```

The SVG file can be read, rasterized and loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with the following function:

```py
from svg import Parser, Rasterizer

def load_svg(filename, scale=None, size=None, clip_from=None, fit_to=None, foramt='RGBA'):
    svg = Parser.parse_file(filename)
    scale = min((fit_to[0] / svg.width, fit_to[1] / svg.height)
                if fit_to else ([scale if scale else 1] * 2))
    width, height = size if size else (svg.width, svg.height)
    surf_size = round(width * scale), round(height * scale)
    buffer = Rasterizer().rasterize(svg, *surf_size, scale, *(clip_from if clip_from else 0, 0))
    return  pygame.image.frombuffer(buffer, surf_size, foramt)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import cairosvg
import pygame
import io

def load_svg(filename):
    new_bites = cairosvg.svg2png(url = filename)
    byte_io = io.BytesIO(new_bites)
    return pygame.image.load(byte_io)

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame_surface = load_svg('Ice-001.svg')
size = pygame_surface.get_size()
scale = min(window.get_width() / size[0], window.get_width() / size[1]) * 0.8
pygame_surface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame_surface, (round(size[0] * scale), round(size[1] * scale)))

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((127, 127, 127))
    window.blit(pygame_surface, pygame_surface.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 16):

There is a new possibility that works and does not require `librsvg` anymore. There is the [Cython wrapper over nanosvg library](https://github.com/ethanhs/pynanosvg) and it works:

```
from svg import Parser, Rasterizer


def load_svg(filename, surface, position, size=None):
    if size is None:
        w = surface.get_width()
        h = surface.get_height()
    else:
        w, h = size
    svg = Parser.parse_file(filename)
    rast = Rasterizer()
    buff = rast.rasterize(svg, w, h)
    image = pygame.image.frombuffer(buff, (w, h), 'ARGB')
    surface.blit(image, position)
```

I found Cairo/rsvg solution too complicated to get to work because of dependencies are quite obscure to install.

Comment: Complete function, all-inclusive -> https://gist.github.com/zgoda/16c4bb767a085743251503471c1faeb1

Comment: Seemed nice, but nanosvg is no longer maintained:
https://github.com/ethanhs/pynanosvg/commit/cc751ffda61c604505a405420c3fcf5689ca6807

Comment: Since Version 2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html).

Comment: Nice answer! But in 2020 it seems that Pynanosvg became inactive and archived on github

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) (with PyCairo), which has support for rendering SVGs. The PyGame webpage has a [HOWTO](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CairoPygame) for rendering into a buffer with a Cairo, and using that buffer directly with PyGame.

Comment: Since Version 2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html).

Answer (score 4):

I realise this doesn't exactly answer your question, but there's a library called [Squirtle](http://www.supereffective.org/?p=14) that will render SVG files using either Pyglet or PyOpenGL.

Comment: Since Version 2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html).

Answer (score 3):

[Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) cannot render SVG out of the box.
It seems we have to use librsvg.

I just found those two pages:

- [Rendering SVG with libRSVG,Python and c-types](http://www.cairographics.org/cookbook/librsvgpython/)
- [How to use librsvg from Python](http://www.cairographics.org/pyrsvg/)

Something like this should probably work (render **test.svg** to **test.png**):

```
import cairo
import rsvg

WIDTH, HEIGHT  = 256, 256
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

ctx = cairo.Context (surface)

svg = rsvg.Handle(file="test.svg")
svg.render_cairo(ctx)

surface.write_to_png("test.png")
```

Comment: SVG files are supported with Pygame Version 2.0. Since Version 2.0.2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html):

Answer (score 2):

[pygamesvg](http://paul.giannaros.org/sandbox_pygamesvg) seems to do what you want (though I haven't tried it).

Comment: That module has been taken down. The cairo+rsvg approaches listed below are much better solutions.
[disclaimer: I quickly wrote pygamesvg 3 years ago]

Comment: Since Version 2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html).

Answer (score 1):

The last comment crashed when I ran it because svg.render_cairo() is expecting a [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) context and not a Cairo surface. I created and tested the following function and it seems to run fine on my system.

```
import array,cairo, pygame,rsvg

def loadsvg(filename,surface,position):
    WIDTH = surface.get_width()
    HEIGHT = surface.get_height()
    data = array.array('c', chr(0) * WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4)
    cairosurface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(data, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT, WIDTH * 4)
    svg = rsvg.Handle(filename)
    svg.render_cairo(cairo.Context(cairosurface))
    image = pygame.image.frombuffer(data.tostring(), (WIDTH, HEIGHT),"ARGB")
    surface.blit(image, position)

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()

loadsvg("test.svg",screen,(0,0))

pygame.display.flip()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    clock.tick(15)
    event = pygame.event.get()
    for e in event:
        if e.type == 12:
            raise SystemExit
```

Comment: SVG files are supported with Pygame Version 2.0. Since Version 2.0.2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html):

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers, here's a function to read a SVG file into a Pygame image—including correcting color channel order and scaling:

```
def pygame_svg(svg_file, scale=1):
    svg = rsvg.Handle(file=svg_file)
    width, height = map(svg.get_property, ("width", "height"))
    width *= scale; height *= scale
    data = array.array('c', chr(0) * width * height * 4)
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(data, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height, width*4)
    ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
    ctx.scale(scale, scale)
    svg.render_cairo(ctx)

    # Seemingly, Cairo and Pygame expect channels in a different order...
    # If colors/alpha are funny, mess with the next lines
    import numpy
    data = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype='uint8')
    data.shape = (height, width, 4)
    c = data.copy()
    data[::, ::, 0] = c[::, ::, 1]
    data[::, ::, 1] = c[::, ::, 0]
    data[::, ::, 2] = c[::, ::, 3]
    data[::, ::, 3] = c[::, ::, 2]

    image = pygame.image.frombuffer(data.tostring(), (width, height), "ARGB")
    return image
```

Comment: SVG files are supported with Pygame Version 2.0. Since Version 2.0.2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html):

Answer (score 0):

Despite [Pygame/SDL new support for SVG files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598021/624066), its rendering features are still very limited, so LibRsvg might still be needed. This is a 2022 update for the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/341742/624066) that works with modern versions of Python, Pygame and Pycairo:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

import cairo
import gi
import PIL.Image
import pygame
gi.require_version('Rsvg', '2.0')
from gi.repository import Rsvg

WIDTH = 512
HEIGHT = 512
PATH = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "test.svg"


def load_svg(path: str, size: tuple) -> pygame.Surface:
    """Render an SVG file to a new pygame surface and return that surface."""
    svg = Rsvg.Handle.new_from_file(path)

    # Create a Cairo surface.
    # Nominally ARGB, but in little-endian architectures it is effectively BGRA
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, *size)

    # Create a Cairo context and scale it
    context = cairo.Context(surface)
    context.scale(size[0]/svg.props.width, size[1]/svg.props.height)

    # Render the SVG
    svg.render_cairo(context)

    # Get image data buffer
    data = surface.get_data()
    if sys.byteorder == 'little':
        # Convert from effective BGRA to actual RGBA.
        # PIL is surprisingly faster than NumPy, but can be done without neither
        data = PIL.Image.frombuffer('RGBA', size, data.tobytes(),
                                    'raw', 'BGRA', 0, 1).tobytes()

    return pygame.image.frombuffer(data, size, "RGBA").convert_alpha()


pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
image = load_svg(PATH, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
window.blit(image, (0, 0))
pygame.display.update()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    if pygame.event.get([pygame.QUIT]):
        break
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```