# Quickest way to convert Cairo Surface to Pygame on OS-X

Tags: python, macos, pygame, cairo

I'm looking for a way to draw smooth animations in Python. I want to use cairo, partly because I like the sub-pixel filtering and partly because I'm familiar with the API. My first approach was to use a GTK.DrawingArea as the target for a cairo surface. While the drawing was quick I couldn't find any reliable way to tie the display / buffering to the vertical sync so the animation was jerky and unreliable.

My next approach was to try PyGame. Using the examples in the [wiki](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CairoPygame) as a starting point I've written some simple code to animate various bouncing balls. The different approaches on the linked page fall into two categories:

1. Draw to an offscreen cairo
   ImageSurface and then use Numpy to
   convert the pixel buffer to a Pygame
   surface.
2. Share the same memory for both
   surfaces

The first approach sucks for performance as the conversion takes about 10ms, which is most of the time-slice that I have for 60hz frames. I'm running the code on a Macbook-pro with 2.2Ghz Core2Duo and an Nvidia 8400. The time is very dependent on the size of the surface, this is for a 800x800 window.

The second approach surfaces from the ordering of pixel coordinates. Both cairo and pygame insist that they can only use RGB pixel ordering and don't support conversion. The problem is that when I setup a pygame surface it uses BGRA pixel ordering, which completely shafts me.

So now for the questions:

1. Is it possible to change the pixel
   format used by either library on the
   mac to be compatible with each
   other?
2. If it is not possible what is the
       fastest way to do the conversion
       purely in Python?
3. If the fastest Python way still
   sucks up most of the time for a
   frame then how can I interface to
   some C code to do the conversion?
4. Depending on how complex the
   interface to C is, how much point is
   there in using pygame instead of
   just writing the SDL interface in C?

.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial also could help you: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CairoPygame

Comment: They all suffer from problem number 2 - the ordering of the colour components is different in the two libraries so it requires some form of conversion. That page is actually where I started a couple of years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

These may be of help [pygame #cairo](http://www.pygame.org/tags/cairo) , [squirtle svg pygame](http://www.pygame.org/project-PyGame+Squirtle+Port-962-.html)

And another thread: [SVG rendering in a PyGame application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120584/svg-rendering-in-a-pygame-application)

Comment: Afraid not - it is something very specific that I was looking for.