# Loading SVG files with python and pygame

Tags: python, svg, pygame, inkscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVG rendering in a PyGame application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120584/svg-rendering-in-a-pygame-application)

Can I load .svg files created by inkscape to python via pygame? And if so, how I can do it?

Comment: The solutions provided in the link are no longer supported in Python 3.9

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot, PyGame supports following image formats:

- JPG
- PNG
- GIF (non animated)
- BMP
- PCX
- TGA (uncompressed)
- TIF
- LBM (and PBM)
- PBM (and PGM, PPM)
- XPM

You can however rasterize that SVG using [**Cairo RSVG** library](http://cairographics.org/pyrsvg/). 
There is some documentation for that on [PyGame's web](http://pygame.org/wiki/CairoPygame).