# How can I draw images and sprites in Pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame

How can I draw images using Pygame? I know how to load them.

I have made a blank window.

When I use `screen.blit(blank, (10,10))`, it does not draw the image and instead leaves the screen blank.

Comment: Did you googled `draw images pygame` ? In my PC I get some useful docs and tutorials

Comment: are we talking about a .png type of image?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a typical layout:

```
myimage = pygame.image.load("myimage.bmp")
imagerect = myimage.get_rect()

while 1:
    your_code_here

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(myimage, imagerect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 8):

Images are represented by ["pygame.Surface"](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) objects. A *Surface* can be created from an image with [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html):

```py
my_image_surface = pygame.load.image('my_image.jpg')
```

However, the Pygame documentation notes that:

> The returned Surface will contain the same color format, colorkey and alpha transparency as the file it came from. You will often want to call [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) with no arguments, to create a copy that will draw more quickly on the screen.
> For alpha transparency, like in .png images, use the [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) method after loading so that the image has per pixel transparency.

Use the appropriate conversion method for best performance:

```py
image_surface = pygame.load.image('my_image.jpg').convert()
```

```py
alpha_image_surface = pygame.load.image('my_icon.png').convert_alpha()
```

A *Surface* can be drawn on or blended with another *Surface* using the [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method. The first argument to blit is the *Surface* that should be drawn. The second argument is either a tuple (*x*, *y*) representing the upper left corner or a rectangle. With a rectangle, only the upper left corner of the rectangle is taken into account. It should be mentioned that the window respectively display is also represented by a *Surface*. Therefore, drawing a *Surface* in the window is the same as drawing a *Surface* on a *Surface*:

```py
window_surface.blit(image_surface, (x, y))
```

```py
window_surface.blit(image_surface,
    image_surface.get_rect(center = window_surface.get_rect().center))
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygameSurface = pygame.image.load('apple.png').convert_alpha()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((127, 127, 127))
    window.blit(pygameSurface, pygameSurface.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

[`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) is bale to load most images. According to the documentation the following formats are supported: JPG, PNG, GIF (non-animated), BMP, PCX, TGA (uncompressed), TIF, LBM (and PBM), PBM (and PGM, PPM), XPM.

If you want to use images in Pygame that are loaded with other libraries, see:

- [PIL and pygame.image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202092/pil-and-pygame-image)
- [How do I convert an OpenCV (cv2) image (BGR and BGRA) to a pygame.Surface object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183409/how-do-i-convert-an-opencv-cv2-image-bgr-and-bgra-to-a-pygame-surface-object/64183410#64183410)

For information on loading [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) (SVG) files, see:

- [SVG rendering in a Pygame application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120584/svg-rendering-in-a-pygame-application)

Loading animated GIF files is presented at:

- [How can I load an animated GIF and get all of the individual frames in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571399/how-can-i-load-an-animated-gif-and-get-all-of-the-individual-frames-in-pygame)
- [How do I make a sprite as a GIF image in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179680/how-do-i-make-a-sprite-as-a-gif-in-pygame/64182074#64182074)

Or see how to load [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) frames:

- [Pygame and NumPy Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415196/pygame-and-numpy-animations)

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))

player = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("player.png"))
player.convert()

while True:
    screen.blit(player, (10, 10))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

It loads the file `player.png`.

Run this and it works perfectly.

Comment: `pygame.quit()` will never be executed and `true` should be `True`

Comment: `convert()` **returns** the new image; it doesn't change the image in-place. So `player.convert()` does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

After using `blit` or any other update on your drawing surface, you have to call `pygame.display.flip()` to actually update what is displayed.