# PIL and pygame.image

Tags: python, image, pygame, python-imaging-library

I had opened an image using PIL, as

```
image = Image.open("SomeImage.png")
```

Draw some text on it, as

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text(Some parameters here)
```

and then saved it as

```
image.save("SomeOtherName.png")
```

to open it using pygame.image

```
this_image = pygame.image.load("SomeOtherName.png")
```

I just want to do it without saving.. Can that be possible? It is taking a lot of time to save and then load(0.12 sec Yes, that is more as I have multiple images which require this operation). Can that save method be surpassed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `fromstring()` function from `pygame.image`. The following should work, according to the documentation:

```
image = Image.open("SomeImage.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text(Some parameters here)

mode = image.mode
size = image.size
data = image.tostring()

this_image = pygame.image.fromstring(data, size, mode)
```

Comment: Just a note: image.tostring() will no longer work, use image.tobytes()

Answer (score 14):

Sadly the accepted answer doesn't work anymore, because `Image.tostring()` has been removed. It has been replaced by `Image.tobytes()`. See [Pillow - `Image` Module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html).

Function to convert a [PIL `Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#) to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object:

```py
def pilImageToSurface(pilImage):
    return pygame.image.fromstring(
        pilImage.tobytes(), pilImage.size, pilImage.mode).convert()
```

It is recommended to [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) the *Surface* to have the same pixel format as the display *Surface*.

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame
from PIL import Image

def pilImageToSurface(pilImage):
    return pygame.image.fromstring(
        pilImage.tobytes(), pilImage.size, pilImage.mode).convert()

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pilImage = Image.open('myimage.png')
pygameSurface = pilImageToSurface(pilImage)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(pygameSurface, pygameSurface.get_rect(center = (250, 250)))
    pygame.display.flip()
```