# How to display an image in Pygame using list of RGBA values of a image

Tags: python, pygame, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a pygame project which involves some images. In these images some are very similar and there is just a change of colour. So I came up with idea that why not to use only one image and change its corresponding colour using Python [from this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pillow-colors-on-an-image/).

```
from PIL import Image
import pygame as pg

img = Image.open("Assets/image.png")
img = img.convert("RGBA")
d = img.getdata()
new_image = []
for item in d:
    if item[:3] == (0,0,0):
        new_image.append((255,255,255,0))
    if item[:3] == (23,186,255):
        new_image.append((255,38,49,item[3]))
    else:
        new_image.append(item)
img.putdata(new_image)
img.save("a.png","PNG")
```

But in the last two lines of the above code its saving the image and I don't want that!
I want to use it in the Pygame code for displaying and then when the program exits the image is gone. So how can I use a list of RGBA values `new _image` to display an image in Pygame.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pygame.image.frombuffer()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer) to create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). However you have to convert the list to a byte array. Use the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module to make a byte array from a list:

```py
flat_list = [e for c in new_image for e in c]
bute_array = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(flat_list))(*flat_list)
surf = pg.image.frombuffer(bute_array, img.size, img.mode).convert_alpha()
```

See also [PIL and pygame.image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202092/pil-and-pygame-image/64182629#64182629).

Notice that there is a bug in your algorithm. You need to use `elif` instead of `if` in the middle case:

```py
if item[:3] == (0,0,0):
    new_image.append((255,255,255,0))

#if item[:3] == (23,186,255):
elif item[:3] == (23,186,255):              # <---

    new_image.append((255,38,49,item[3]))
else:
    new_image.append(item)
```

Note: if you want to change the background to a white color, you need to make the color opaque:

<s>`new_image.append((255,255,255,0))`</s>

```py
new_image.append((255, 255, 255, 255))
```

---

Minimal example:

The left image is the test image and the right image is the result:

[image]
[image]

```py
from PIL import Image
import pygame as pg
import ctypes

img = Image.open("Assets/image.png")
img = img.convert("RGBA")
d = img.getdata()
new_image = []
for item in d:
    if item[:3] == (0, 0, 0):
        new_image.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        #new_image.append((255, 255, 255, 255))
    elif item[:3] == (23, 186, 255):
        new_image.append((255, 38, 49, item[3]))
    else:
        new_image.append(item)

pg.init()
window = pg.display.set_mode(img.size)

flat_list = [e for c in new_image for e in c]
bute_array = (ctypes.c_ubyte * len(flat_list))(*flat_list)
surf = pg.image.frombuffer(bute_array, img.size, img.mode).convert_alpha()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(surf, (0, 0))
    pg.display.flip()

pg.quit()
```

---

Side note:

You don't need to load the image using PLI you can access the pixels of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) directly. There are different options:

- with the methods [`get_at`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at) / [`set_at`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_at)
- with [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) object
- with the [`pygame.surfarray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) module

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks for your answer. I have tested it works also about the bug you said seems like a bug but is not a bug I want to change the blue colour `(23,186,255)` to red colour `(255,38,49)` and I want to make the background `(0,0,0)` transparent. Also thank you for your side note I will try that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely missing the point of your question, but as I understand it, you want to load an image and change some colours. I would do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import pygame as pg
import numpy as np

# Open image and ensure RGBA mode, not palette image
img = Image.open("image.png").convert('RGBA')

# Define some colours for readability
black = [0,0,0]
white = [255,255,255]
red   = [255,0,0]
blue  = [0,0,255]

# Make image into Numpy array for vectorised processing
na  = np.array(img)

# Make re-usable mask of black pixels then change them to white
mBlack = np.all(na[...,:3] == black, axis=-1)
na[mBlack,:3] = white
# Make re-usable mask of red pixels then change them to blue
mRed  = np.all(na[...,:3] == red, axis=-1)
na[mRed,:3] = blue

pg.init()
window = pg.display.set_mode(img.size)

surf = pg.image.frombuffer(na.tobytes(), img.size, img.mode)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(surf, (0, 0))
    pg.display.flip()

pg.quit()
```

Which makes this image:

[image]

display like this:

[image]

So you can see the power of the masks I made, you can do things like this:

```
# Make any pixels that were either red or black become magenta
na[mRed|mBlack,:3] = [255,0,255]
```

Or:

```
# Make all pixels that were not black into cyan
na[~mBlack,:3] = [0,255,255]
```