# Running into errors with pygame.image.fromstring() arguments

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, python-imaging-library

I would like to be able to display a PIL image object created from a numpy array of 8 bit integers (essentially just a grayscale image) using pygame, but have been running into several errors in the process. Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202092/pil-and-pygame-image), I tried using this function:

```py
def pilImageToSurface(pilImage):
    return pygame.image.fromstring(
        pilImage.tobytes(), pilImage.size,pilImage.mode)
```

to take my PIL image object (created from a numpy array with datatype `np.uint8`) and convert it to a pygame surface, but it would return the error

> ValueError: Unrecognized type of format

I tried troubleshooting this by printing out `pilImage.mode` which returned 'L'. simply replacing `pilImage.mode` with 'L' in the function returned the same error. When I tried the format 'P', it simply displayed a solid gray image. What can I do to rectify this? here is an example of what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pygame
#initiating pygame and displaying a blank image to the screen
pygame.init()
white = (255, 255, 255)
X = 1920
Y = 1080
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((X, Y ))
pygame.display.set_caption('Image')
display_surface.fill(white)
#make PIL image object from a numpy array
imagelist = ((0,1,2,3),(255,254,253,252),(100,101,102,103)) #example array
imagearray = np.array(imagelist,dtype = np.uint8)
imagedata = Image.fromarray(imagearray)
def pilImageToSurface(pilImage):
    return pygame.image.fromstring(
        pilImage.tobytes(), pilImage.size,pilImage.mode)
pygameimage = pilImageToSurface(imagedata)
display_surface.blit(pygame_image, (0, 0)) #sends image to the display
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert the numpy array to a PIL image and the PLI image to a pygame.Surface? The array can be directly loaded into a Surface. Anyway, what is the size of the image? 1x3?

Comment: I wasn't aware that the array could be loaded as a surface. How would one do that? the actual size of the image that I need is 1920x1080, I was just using that array as an example.

Comment: You have to specify the size somewhere. PLI and pygame cannot guess the size of the image.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to load the  [numpy](https://numpy.org/) array into a PLI image and that image into a `pygame.Surface`. A numpy array can be loaded directly into a `pygame.Surface` using [`pygame.image.frombuffer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer):

```py
imagelist = ((0,1,2,3), (255,254,253,252), (100,101,102,103))
imagearray = np.array(imagelist,dtype = np.uint8)
pygame_surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(imagearray.flatten(), (3, 1), 'RGBA')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this with an array size (1080,1920) and used the function `pygame_surface = pygame.image.frombuffer(imagearray.flatten(),(1080,1920),'RGBA')` and recieved an error, "ValueError: Buffer length does not equal format and resolution size". why might this be occurring?

Comment: @JBowers Yes of course, You have to create an array with 1080*1920*4 bytes.  Your array has just 12 bytes. You can create an array with zeros: `imagearray = np.zeros(shape = (1080, 1920, 4), dtype = np.uint8)`.