# Why is this image not appearing on screen?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

As far as i know this is all i should have to do to display and image on the screen but it doesn't. I know i must be missing something fairly obvious here but i can't see what i have missed out that is not letting my image appear on screen.

main.py

```
import pygame
from loading import *
from settings import *

class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameRunning = True
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.Background_images = load_images()

    def gameLoop(self):

        self.clock.tick(fps)
        self.event()
        self.update()

    def event(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.gameRunning = False

    def update(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.Background_images["layer1"], (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()

playGame = game()
while playGame.gameRunning == True:
    playGame.gameLoop()
```

loading.py

```
import pygame
from settings import *

def load_images():
    Parallax_images = {}
    Parallax_images["layer1"] = pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer1.png")
    Parallax_images["layer2"] = pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer2.png")
    Parallax_images["layer3"] = pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer3.png")
    Parallax_images["layer4"] = pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer4.png")
    Parallax_images["layer5"] = pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer5.png")
    Parallax_images["layer6"] = pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer6.png")
    Parallax_images["layer7"] = pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer7.png")
    Parallax_images["layer8"] = pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer8.png")
    return Parallax_images
```

Comment: Where are screen_width and screen_height created? If you blit onto a nonexistent screen, nothing will happen. Are you getting any errors, or just  a blank screen?

Comment: they are created in settings.py which i imported at the top. Also the pygame window opens fine but it's completely black. The code also works with different images just not the ones i'm using. So i think the issue is with the images not the code.

Comment: Do the pngs have some blank/empty areas? If so, maybe, when you load an image, use : `pygame.image.load("PARALLAX\layer1.png").convert_alpha()`

Answer (score 0):

this post was usefull for drawing images

[What is a good way to draw images using pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/what-is-a-good-way-to-draw-images-using-pygame)

**UPDATE**

There appears to be something amiss with the png images themselves. When compiled and run with different images, the code works properly.

Comment: I know that you can blit using an x and y for the top left corner of where you want to image to blit. Also i just tried using a rectangle and still nothing is displayed.

Comment: can you confirm that it is actually getting into the update method?

Comment: Just checked, it's 100% getting to the update method and it's also 100% getting through the load_images method

Comment: I just compiled and ran it with my own images and it works, is there any other info that would be helpful? are the screen dimensions set proper as well as the fps?

Comment: I just went and tried the code with different images and it works fine for them. i'll just have to get different images i think

Comment: seems that way, there must be something about the current images that causes issues. If you figure out why those particular pngs won't work, you should edit the question with what you find. It might be helpful to others

Comment: Blit does not require a rect, just coords, formatted (x, y)

Comment: @C._ I updated the post to eliminate the "requiring a blit" portion, because blits don't require one (but will accept one if given). The original posters code works, but the pngs he was using were bad. When switched for different images, it worked.

Comment: Ok sounds great! +1