# How to draw an image in (pygame)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

I want to replace this draw rectangle function, and instead let it produce an image.

Rectangle Function:

```
pygame.draw.rect(pygame.display.set_mode((800,600)), black, [0,0, 100, 100])
```

Looking for something on the lines of this:

```
pygame.draw.image(**coordinatesX**, **coordinatesY**, **imagefile.jpg**)
```

Comment: This link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/what-is-a-good-way-to-draw-images-using-pygame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good way to draw images using pygame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/what-is-a-good-way-to-draw-images-using-pygame)

Answer (score 1):

To load an image, you need the file stored, and you load it using:

```
pygame.image.load('example.png')
```

Now your code should look like:

```
pygame.image.load('example.png')

pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
```

Answer (score 0):

so first you have to load the image using `image = pygame.image.load()` and then use `screen.blit(image)` to draw it on the screen. For this to work you should define the screen at the beginning not in the draw function like you have done above. Just `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))` should work.