# Making and using pygame sprites for donkey kong style game

Tags: python, pygame

For my project i am recreating donkey kong in pygame, and ive got to the stage where i need sprites for my ladders, platforms and my character, but im unsure how to make sprites and then use these in pygame.

Comment: This question seems a bit too broad - you might want to narrow it down to a specific problem you're facing currently. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example for using a *Sprite* in pygame (see also [Sprite](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_sprite_and_sprite_mask.md#sprite)):

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Sprite](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Sprite#main.py)</kbd>

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self, center_pos, image):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center_pos)
    
    def update(self, surf):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_d]-keys[pygame.K_a]) * 5
        self.rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_s]-keys[pygame.K_w]) * 5
        self.rect.clamp_ip(surf.get_rect())

player_surf = pygame.image.load('Bird64.png').convert_alpha()
player = Player(window.get_rect().center, player_surf)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([player])

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_sprites.update(window)

    window.fill(0)
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

An image can be loaded to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load). See [How to draw images and sprites in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/how-to-draw-images-and-sprites-in-pygame/64630591#64630591).

Pygame uses [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Spritel) objects and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) objects to manage *Sprites*. [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]