# python pygame: Draw loaded image at current mouse click position

Tags: python, image, pygame, click, draw

I'm trying to get a loaded image displayed at the current mouse click position in pygame...
Please help me...
What I'm doing wrong?

```
import pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25  # for more than 220 it has no time to update screen

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()


def main():

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    image = pygame.image.load('images/explo_trans.png').convert()
    image_rect = image.get_rect()
    all_items = []
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    running = True
    while running:

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x, y = event.pos
                image_rect.x = x
                image_rect.y = y
                item = {
                    'rect': image_rect,
                    'remove_at': current_time + 500,  # 500ms = 0.5s
                    }
                all_items.append(item)
                print("add at:", x, y)

        keep_items = []

        for item in all_items:
            if item['remove_at'] > current_time:
                keep_items.append(item)
            else:
                print('removed:', item)

        all_items = keep_items

        screen.fill(BLACK)

        for item in all_items:
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, item['rect'])
            screen.blit(item['rect'], (x, y))

        pygame.display.flip()

        ms = clock.tick(FPS)
        # pygame.display.set_caption('{}ms'.format(ms)) # 40ms for 25FPS, 16ms for 60FPS
        fps = clock.get_fps()
        pygame.display.set_caption('FPS: {}'.format(fps))

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The 1st argument of [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) is the image (`pygame.Surface`) and the 2nd argument is the position:

<s>`screen.blit(item['rect'], (x, y))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(image, item['rect'])
```

See also [What is a good way to draw images using pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/what-is-a-good-way-to-draw-images-using-pygame/64630591#64630591)