# How do I blit an image onto a specific rect?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner in Pygame and I'm having trouble trying to blit an image onto specific rects.

```
obstacle_width = 70
obstacle_height = random.randint(150, 450)
obstacle_colour = (211, 253, 117)
obstacle_x_change = -4
obstacle_x = 500
obstacle_gap = 170


def display_obstacle(height):
    top = pygame.draw.rect(screen, obstacle_colour,
                     (obstacle_x, 0, obstacle_width, height))
    bottom_obstacle_height = 635 - height - obstacle_gap
    bottom = pygame.draw.rect(screen, obstacle_colour,
                     (obstacle_x, height + obstacle_gap, obstacle_width,
                      bottom_obstacle_height))
```

I want to blit an image inside both the `top` and the `bottom` rects. I know how to add an image onto Pygame, but I want the image to be **inside** the rects, instead of above/below them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See  [What is a good way to draw images using pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/what-is-a-good-way-to-draw-images-using-pygame/64630591#64630591). Load the image with [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load)

```py
obstacle_image = pygame.image.load("obstacle.png")
```

Get the bounding rectangle of the image. Create a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for the obstacle. Set the center of the bounding rectangle through the center of the obstacle rectangle and use it to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the image on the screen:

```py
obstacle_rect = pygame.Rect(obstacle_x, height + obstacle_gap, obstacle_width, bottom_obstacle_height)
image_rect = obstacle_image.get_rect(center = obstacle_rect.center)
screen.blit(obstacle_image, image_rect)
```