# How to use sprites in PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw 3 rows of rectangles. In doing so, I want to use pygame.sprite. Group(). I get the error message: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable.I checked the error message here.
Unfortunately I still don't understand why I get this error message. My pygame knowledge is not that deep.

```
import pygame, sys
import random
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
bg = (173,216,230)
breite = 1000
hoehe = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((breite,hoehe))

class Boden:
    def __init__(self):      
        self.blocks = []
        self.spalten =20
        self.sp = breite // self.spalten # breite des rechtecks
        self.ho = 10 # höhe des rechtecks
        self.zeilen = 3
        self.counter_z = -1 
        self.counter_s = -1        
    def bauboden(self):  
        self.counter_z +=0
        for i in range(self.zeilen):
            self.counter_z += 1          
            for j in range(self.spalten):
                self.counter_s += 1 
                block =  pygame.Rect[(i * self.ho,self.sp * j,self.sp,self.ho)]              
                alle_sprites.add(block) 
                self.blocks.add(self.block)


alle_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group() 
boden = pygame.sprite.Group()
boden = Boden()
boden.bauboden()

alle_sprites.add(boden)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()        
    alle_sprites.draw(screen)    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem has nothing to do with `pygame.sprite.Group()`. However, [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is an object:

<s>`block =  pygame.Rect[(i * self.ho,self.sp * j,self.sp,self.ho)]`</s>

```py
block =  pygame.Rect(i * self.ho,self.sp * j,self.sp,self.ho)
```

---

But still you can't add a `pygame.Rect` to a `pygame.sprite.Group()`.

<s>`alle_sprites.add(block)`</s>

You have to create a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` object. Here is a very basic example for using a *Sprite* in pygame (see also [Sprite](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_sprite_and_sprite_mask.md#sprite)):

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Sprite](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Sprite#main.py)</kbd>

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self, center_pos, image):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center_pos)
    
    def update(self, surf):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_d]-keys[pygame.K_a]) * 5
        self.rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_s]-keys[pygame.K_w]) * 5
        self.rect.clamp_ip(surf.get_rect())

player_surf = pygame.image.load('Bird64.png').convert_alpha()
player = Player(window.get_rect().center, player_surf)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([player])

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_sprites.update(window)

    window.fill(0)
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

An image can be loaded to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load). See [How to draw images and sprites in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/how-to-draw-images-and-sprites-in-pygame/64630591#64630591).

A [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) encapsulates an [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object and an [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. It should have and an `image` and a `rect` attribute. `image` stores the sprite and `rect` stores the position and size of the sprite.

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The latter delegates to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) — you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group. [...]

The former uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

The *Sprites* in the *Groups* can be removed and thus destroyed by calling [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite). When the object is no longer referenced, it is destroyed:

> The Sprite is removed from all the Groups that contain it. This won't change anything about the state of the Sprite. It is possible to continue to use the Sprite after this method has been called, including adding it to Groups.