# How do I increase a variable by 1 every time a sprite is clicked and then print the variable

Tags: python, variables, events, pygame, sprite

I have tried to get the variable 'clicks' by 1 every time the red sprite is clicked. Then I need the variable to update so that I can print out the updated number of clicks.

What i have tried:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Printing")
window.fill((0, 0, 0))
rectangle = pygame.draw.rect(window, [255, 0, 0], [50, 50, 90, 90], 0)
pygame.display.flip()

allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
allsprites.add(rectangle)

clicks = 0

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        clicked_sprites = [rectangle for rectangle in allsprites if rectangle.rect.collidepoint(pos)]
        clicks += 1
print(clicks)

# loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

pygame.quit()
```

Problems:

```py
allsprites.add(rectangle)
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'pygame.Rect'

Answer (score 0):

See [How can I add objects to a "pygame.sprite.Group()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924256/how-can-i-add-objects-to-a-pygame-sprite-group/73924281#73924281). You cannot add rectangle to a `pygame.sprite.Group()`. You have to crate a `pygame.sprite.Sprite` object.

```py
class RectSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect):
        super().__init__() 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
```

See [Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection/64533684#64533684). You have check if the event `key` is `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` and the `button` is `BUTTON_LEFT`. Use the `pos` attribute to get the position of the mouse curser. Increment `clicks` only if you find a collision:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
        clicked_sprites = [rectangle for rectangle in allsprites if rectangle.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)]
        if clicked_sprites:
            clicks += 1
```

You have to do all that in the application loop. Complete example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Printing")

class RectSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect):
        super().__init__() 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))

allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
rectangle = RectSprite((50, 50, 90, 90))
allsprites.add(rectangle)

clicks = 0

# loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
                clicked_sprites = [rectangle for rectangle in allsprites if rectangle.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)]
                if clicked_sprites:
                    clicks += 1
                    print(clicks)

    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    allsprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```