# Pygame .blit() not working in class, or in game loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was following a pygame tutorial, tested to see if the player blit was working and it wasnt, checked for problems but there were none that I could find, and then I tested a .blit() directly in the game loop and that didnt work so I've been stumped for a good bit now.

player class below, "Player_Down" should be irrelevant rn since its just an image

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        direction = "down"
        self.image = player_down
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


ply = Player(SCREEN_WIDTH // 2 , SCREEN_HEIGHT - 150)
```

Game loop with draw function called

```
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((83,90,83))
    ply.draw()
    
    #event handler
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print("Game quit via X button")
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This was the best I could do because I didnt find a problem with the code, and the only thing I modified before the problem arose was the class and while loop to add ply.draw()

Comment: Seems the draw function is being called but the blit is not working

Comment: Are the code snippets in different files? Is `screen` in `Player` the same screen as in the application loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the code in the question. Your suspicion that `blit` does not work is wrong (alos see [How to draw images and sprites in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873219/how-to-draw-images-and-sprites-in-pygame)). The code works fine.
However, I suggest passing the `screen` *Surface* as an argument to `draw` method. See the minimal and working example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

player_down = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
player_down.fill((255, 0, 0))

class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        direction = "down"
        self.image = player_down
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)
    def draw(self, surf):
        surf.blit(self.image, self.rect)


ply = Player(SCREEN_WIDTH // 2 , SCREEN_HEIGHT - 150)

running = True
while running:
    
    #event handler
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print("Game quit via X button")
            running = False

    screen.fill((83,90,83))
    ply.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```