# How to load a complex SVG into pygame correctly?

Tags: python, svg, pygame, python-chess

I am making a chess game in Python with PyGame using the python-chess library.

When I implement my program in PyGame the window only shows the empty board without the pieces. However, if I manually open the svg file that my code generates it shows correctly, with the pieces on the board. The problem is - when using `blit` to display the same image in PyGame I get an empty board.

To be clear, the issue is not a general 'loading SVG in PyGame' question. I am successfully displaying my SVG in this example. The question is a PyGame/python-chess question: 
Why is PyGame loading the image that has the pieces in it as an empty board if it's the same file?

Code:

```
import pygame as pg
import chess
import chess.svg
import chess.pgn

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WINDOW = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption('Opening mastery')
FPS = 60

board = chess.BaseBoard()

def get_board_img(brd):
    SVG = chess.svg.board(board=brd)
    f = open("image.svg", "w")
    f.write(SVG)
    f.close()
    image = ('image.svg')
    return image



def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False
        image = get_board_img(board)
        WINDOW.blit(pg.image.load(image),(0,0))
        pg.display.update()
        
           
    pg.quit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the generated SVG file opened manually (it has the pieces)
[image]

This is the result (no pieces on the board)
[image]

Comment: Perhaps because your function writes to a file named `image.SVG`, but returns the filename `image.svg`?  Those are not the same filename.

Comment: Good call but after editing both to be image.svg the same thing happens

Comment: I'd suggest you save the board as a png image (or convert to a png) and load that instead. You may also be able to use pillow library to load the image and then use `pygame.image.frombytes` to load a PIL.Image

Comment: An SVG file is a text file (XML). If I run your code and open the "image.svg" file with a text editor, I can clearly see all the information about the figures in the file. So it is indeed an SVG problem and a bug in the Pygame SVG engine. So your code is correct and there is no answer to your question other than to create a Pygame issue report (https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues) and use something other than Pygame to read the SVG. See [SVG rendering in PyGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120584/svg-rendering-in-a-pygame-application-prior-to-pygame-2-0-pygame-did-not-suppo).

Answer (score 3):

It appears that pygame's SVG loading library (nanosvg) can't handle that SVG.

I found a workaround using cairosvg to convert the SVG to a PNG and then using pygame to load that.

I made a new `get_board_image` function that returns a surface directly

```py
def get_board_img(brd):
    svg = chess.svg.board(board=brd)
    png_io = io.BytesIO()
    cairosvg.svg2png(bytestring=bytes(svg, "utf8"), write_to=png_io)
    png_io.seek(0)

    surf = pg.image.load(png_io, "png")
    return surf
```

It uses cairosvg to get the svg bytes into a png BytesIO object that pygame can load.

^ To get that snippet working in your code you need to add the imports for `io` and `cairosvg` (and install cairosvg) ofc, as well as changing your main loop a bit:

```py
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False
        WINDOW.blit(get_board_img(board),(0,0))
        pg.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as OP, and I noticed that the individual chess pieces that can be output as SVG by the `chess.svg.piece` function work without need of `cairosvg`.

So I cooked up a function that places all the pieces by hand.

```
empty_board = pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(str(chess.svg.board()).encode('utf-8')))
symbol = {
    'K': pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(str(
            chess.svg.piece(chess.Piece.from_symbol('K'))).encode('utf-8')))
    'Q': ...
}

symbol_size = symbol['K'].get_size()
border = (empty_board.get_size()[0] - 8 * symbol_size[0]) // 2,
         (empty_board.get_size()[1] - 8 * symbol_size[1]) // 2

def draw(board, screen):
    screen.blit(empty_board, (0, 0))
    x, y = 0, 0
    for c in str(board):
        if c == '\n':
            y += 1
            x = 0
        if c in symbol:
            screen.blit(symbol[c], (symbol_size[0] * x + border[0],
                                    symbol_size[1] * y + border[1]))
        if c in symbol or c == '.':
            x += 1
```

This has the advantage that all the SVG rendering can be done up-front rather then after every change of the board, and then the final chessboard is put together just using `blit` method.

I uploaded a working example to https://github.com/matthias-ae/pygame-chess (split it up in two files in the end).
You can go back to the first commit if you're only interested in this question and don't want to actually play chess :-)